# I am trying to find the sql query to get the red boxed items from the diagram. What is the query to get the red boxed columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have been trying to the sql query for the columns in the red box, any assistance would be helpful.

I tried this query:

```
SELECT

Employees.LastName,

Employees.FirstName,

Region.RegionDescription

FROM

    (
    
        (
    
            (Employees 
    
                LEFT JOIN
    
                EmployeeTerritories 
    
                    ON Employees.EmployeeID = EmployeeTerritories.EmployeeID) 
    
        LEFT JOIN
    
        Territories 
    
            ON EmployeeTerritories.EmployeeID = Territories.TerritoryID) 
    
    LEFT JOIN
    
      Region 
    
        ON Territories.RegionID = Region.RegionID
    
    );
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the expected output, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Unfortunately this is all the information I was provided and told my query is not correct. For the life of me, I can't figure out what else could it be.

Comment: If you don't have more information, how could you check whether any other query is working?

Comment: Was thinking someone more experienced in SQL might be able to help figure out the query. If the question itself is wrong, than that's what might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join with Territories was on EmployeeID *`(EmployeeTerritories.EmployeeID = Territories.TerritoryID)`*, but should be on `EmployeeTerritories.TerritoryID = Territories.TerritoryID`. And removed all the brackets, makes it easier to read. Does this work for you?

```
SELECT
  Employees.LastName,
  Employees.FirstName,
  Region.RegionDescription
FROM Employees 
LEFT JOIN EmployeeTerritories 
ON Employees.EmployeeID = EmployeeTerritories.EmployeeID
LEFT JOIN Territories 
ON EmployeeTerritories.TerritoryID = Territories.TerritoryID
LEFT JOIN Region 
ON Territories.RegionID = Region.RegionID
```

Answer (score 0):

please check   second join

ON EmployeeTerritories.EmployeeID = Territories.TerritoryID)
should be
ON EmployeeTerritories.TerritoryID = Territories.TerritoryID)

here is changed  SQL

```
   SELECT
    Employees.LastName,    
    Employees.FirstName,    
    Region.RegionDescription    
    FROM    
        (
          (        
                (Employees         
                    LEFT JOIN
                    EmployeeTerritories         
                        ON Employees.EmployeeID = EmployeeTerritories.EmployeeID)         
            LEFT JOIN        
            Territories         
                ON EmployeeTerritories.TerritoryID = Territories.TerritoryID)         
        LEFT JOIN        
          Region         
            ON Territories.RegionID = Region.RegionID        
        );
```